# Using _FILES Not able to send file to PHP server

Tags: php, android, json, smarty

I am trying to send values to PHP server but always,i get HTTP REsponse 200 and in my server i am not getting the value i sent,dont know what is the issue following is my snippet code for android and PHP,can any one help me with this?..sorry for to much code......i also followed this [Android file upload - $_FILES returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369277/android-file-upload-files-returns-empty)

PHP side i used smarty framework

```
 $print = false;
 $header = true;
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] =='imagetest')
{ 
$error = '0';
$val = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
if($val != '')
{
    $error = '1';
    $msg = 'Image Not Upload Please Try Agin';
    $param = array("status"=>"error","msg"=>$val);
    $val = json_encode($param);
    echo $val;
    exit;
}
/*if($_FILES['image'] == '')
{
    $error = '1';
    $msg = 'Image Not Upload Please Try Agin';
    $param = array("status"=>"error","msg"=>$msg);
    $val = json_encode($param);
    echo $val;
    exit;
}*/
if($error == '0')
{ 

    $target_path = "uploads/";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        $msg = 'Image inserted successfully';
        $param = array("status"=>"success","msg"=>$msg);
        $val = json_encode($param);
        echo $val;
        exit;
    } else{
        $msg = 'Image not inserted successfully';
        $param = array("status"=>"success","msg"=>$msg);
        $val = json_encode($param);
        echo $val;
        exit;
    }
}
}
 else
  {
$msg = 'something went wrong';
$param = array("status"=>"success","msg"=>$msg);
$val = json_encode($param);
echo $val;
exit;
  }
```

MyjavaFile

```
   uploadButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
      uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {            
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PhotoUpload.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
           new Thread(new Runnable()
           {
                   public void run() 
                   {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                               public void run() 
                               {
                                messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                               }
                           });                      
                    uploadFile(selectedImagePath);                       
                   }
                 }).start();        
           }
       });
  }



   @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == 1111) {

          if (data!=null ) {
                    openGalleryImage(data);
                    //saveImage(uri_outputFileUri.getPath());
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    try {
                        bitmap = scaleImage(PhotoUpload.this,selectedImageUri);
                        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }         

          }
            }

          }

   public static Bitmap scaleImage(Context context, Uri photoUri) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
        is.close();

        int rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight;
        int orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri);

        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight;
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth;
        } else {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth;
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight;
        }

        Bitmap srcBitmap;
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        if (rotatedWidth > 100 || rotatedHeight > 100) {
            float widthRatio = ((float) rotatedWidth) / ((float) 100);
            float heightRatio = ((float) rotatedHeight) / ((float) 100);
            float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);

            // Create the bitmap from file
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = (int) maxRatio;
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        } else {
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
        is.close();


        if (orientation > 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(orientation);

            srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(),
                    srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        String type = context.getContentResolver().getType(photoUri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (type.equals("image/png")) {
            srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        } else if (type.equals("image/jpg") || type.equals("image/jpeg")) {
            srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        }
        byte[] bMapArray = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
    }

    public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        /* it's on the external media. */
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    private void openGalleryImage(Intent data) 
    {
        Uri selectedimg = data.getData();
        Uri uriselectedimage=data.getData();
        mString=uriselectedimage.getPath();
        try 
        {
            mInputStream= getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedimg);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] path = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(selectedimg, path, null, null,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(path[0]);
        selectedImagePath=c.getString(columnIndex);
        uri_outputFileUri= Uri.parse(selectedImagePath);
        c.close();
    }

    private void saveImage(String mPath) 
    {

        System.out.println("Paths  "+mPath);
            mediaDir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/MyFolder");
            mediaDir.mkdir();


        File myImage = new File(mediaDir, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png");

        try 
        { 
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
            mbitmap_outputImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);    
            mbitmap_outputImage=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mbitmap_outputImage, 390, 310, true);
            mbitmap_outputImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 
            img.setImageBitmap(mbitmap_outputImage);
            out.flush();    
            out.close();

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }  

    }    

      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
         public String getPath(Uri uri) {
   String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
   Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
   int column_index =    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


     DataOutputStream dos = null;  
     String lineEnd = "\r\n";
     String twoHyphens = "--";
     String boundary = "*****";
     int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
     byte[] buffer;
     int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
     File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 


     if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               + selectedImagePath);


           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           + selectedImagePath);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;
     }
     else
     {
           try { 
                 /* btns=uploadButton.getTag().toString();
                System.out.println(btns);*/
                  String fileName = sourceFileUri;
                  File f  = new File(selectedImagePath);
                 imgs= f.getName();
                System.out.println(imgs);

                upLoadServerUri = "http://www.asdf.com/web-service/imagetest.php?action=imagetest&image="+imgs;


                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet


               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
               System.out.println(url);
               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("image", imgs);
                 //  conn.setRequestProperty("user_login_id", User_ID);
                  // conn.setRequestProperty("action", "addproduct");
                  // conn.setRequestProperty("version", "apps");

               dos  = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                 // add parameters
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\""
                         + lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                 // assign value


                    // send image
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='image';filename='"
                         + imgs + "'" + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        public void run() {


                            try 
                            {


                                DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                                String inputLine;
                                while ((inputLine = dataIn.readLine()) != null) 
                                {
                                    result += inputLine;
                                    System.out.println("Result : " + result);
                                }
                                //result=getJSONUrl(url);  //<< get json string from server
                                //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result);
                                sta = jobj.getString("status");
                                msg = jobj.getString("msg");
                                System.out.println(sta + " >>>>>>> " + msg);

                               // new LoadImages().execute();
                               /* Intent intent=new Intent(PhotoUpload.this,PhotoView.class);
                                startActivity(intent);*/



                            } 
                            catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload image to a PHP server using an android application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140878/how-to-upload-image-to-a-php-server-using-an-android-application)

Comment: @MurtazaHussain can you tell whats the issue?

Comment: `image is not displaying in server side` ? Where should it display?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android multipart upload with image list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931932/android-multipart-upload-with-image-list)

Comment: I follow this tutorial and it worked perfectly http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/file-upload-on-php-server-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this nice tutorial "[Android Uploading Camera Image, Video to Server with Progress Bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)"

Comment: thanks i vote up but
I follow this tutorial and it worked perfectly http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/file-upload-on-php-server-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the length of the file in the header. It seems some servers may reject the file if there is no Content-Length header. E.g.:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(fileInputStream.available()));
```